# Should I "un-favorite" some old questions?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

Over the years I have marked many post as Favorites. The list has become long enough that it's unwieldy and less than helpful. Many of the questions are no longer topical- I've already learned from them! I want to winnow down the list.

But the amount of Favorite marks given to a question is one of the metrics we use to show how awesome it is. We give out badges :)  So I don't (necessarily) want to penalize questions just because I'm done with them.

What is the preferred way to handle this? Should I:

1. Feel free to keep my Favorites list tight and useful, or
2. Let the list grow, as to not remove Favorite marks from good questions?

Comment: I would take out the trash and only use the ones that are your most favorite

Answer (score 6):

You should definitely remove them from *your* favorites. Don't game the system. Presumably a functioning list is more useful to you than a virtual badge on someone's profile page.